# Which of the following is not used to determine the slope of a function algebraically?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I dont know the answer to the above question. I think it is the slope of a secant line but I'm not sure

```
a. slope of a secant line
b. graphing calculator
c. difference quotient
d. rationalizing numerator
```

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, possibly the "rationalizing" of the numerator is in the context of finding the derivative of $\sqrt x$, for example. See here:http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der01/der01a.html

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Hadn't thought of that, thanks, you're quite right. Deleting comment. So it's the graphing calculator?

Comment: That's my best guess. I'm not overly impressed with this question, to say the least...

Comment: I think this link can help: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-point-slope.html and http://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/derivatives-introduction.html

Comment: @TheChaz2.0, I agree.

Comment: The *algebraically* presumably is intended to settle things, though many graphing calculators do algebraic manipulations. One of the (many) objectionable features of multiple choice questions is that question makers try to fool students into making "wrong" choices.

Answer (score 1):

All of the given options can actually be used to find the slope of a function:

1. The slope of the secant line is the difference quotient.
2. A good graphing calculator (e.g. TI-89 or HP-50G) can find it algebraically.
3. Taking the limit of the difference quotient gives the slope of the function.
4. Rationalizing the numerator could be done as part of taking a limit (e.g. [this example](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der01/der01a.html) from the comments.)

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is true!
a. slope of a secant line
actually slope of tangent line determines slope of a function

Comment: How do you find the slope of the tangent line?